# Denied SYSTEM access to my drive, how to re-enable it?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, security

I gone into my drives properties and denied SYSTEM's access to it:

[image]

Now I can't access that drive and can't find a way to return the system access.

Tried to add it this way but it didn't work:

[image]

Connected the hard drive to another computer and even restored my PC but looks like it's saved into the drive and not the operating system.
I'm using windows 7

How do I re-enable it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Have a look at this Microsoft Community post to see if it can help you - [How to restore Default Security Permissions](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-to-restore-default-security-permissions/ab58f918-da72-42c0-ba71-161d52b73d46?auth=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried this before, and I think it is good enough to

1. take ownership (to your current user ID), that works if you are admin;
2. then in a second step change the authorizations for 'System' (as the owner, you are always implicitly authorized to do such things)

Comment: taking the ownership was the step I needed to take thank you ^_^

Answer (score 0):

A few of the posts in this thread may be able to help:

http://forums.majorgeeks.com/index.php?threads/restore-default-windows-permissions.274623/

To quote:

To restore access permissions, the following will need to be entered into an admin command prompt:

icacls "d:" /reset /T /C

This will reset the access permissions back to what they were upon install.

If this doesn't work, a person has a couple of choices:

1. Run dism /online /cleanup-image /restoreheatlh in admin cmd. I don't believe this advanced command was included in Win 7 by default, so a requirement for this would be to download the Windows 7 WAIK from Microsoft.com which would include the full Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment
2. Attempt to use dism with the /source command, however, the source must be either a Windows installation disk for your architecture of Windows, or an offline Windows installation of the same architecture which DISM can copy files from
3. The easiest way, although more time consuming, will be to use your Windows Installation Media to "upgrade" to the same version and architecture of Windows that is currently installed. This is called a Repair Install and it must be performed like an upgrade, i.e. the installation must be rain from within the booted OS, and the "upgrade" option must be selected. This will allow you to keep all installed programs and user data, although there may be a handful of programs and drivers that may need to be installed if they installed files into the %windir% [Windows Folder], as a repair install replaces all system files within the %windir% and a select few other locations.